Scanner not detected on USB port
I have an old Epson 2450 scanner which I have been using for years with the Epson 4990 driver, including for the past year or so on Windows 11.
But during the past week, the scanner is no longer detected. It is not seen in Device Manager even as an unknown device.
I am running Windows 11 Pro 23H2 with the latest security updates.Microsoft Windows 11 Pro Version 10.0.22631 Build 22631
I have

Rebooted the computer
Disconnected and reconnected the scanner power off and power on
Tried different ports, including a legacy USB 2.0 port
Done "Scan for Hardware Changes" in Device manager.
Ensured the port I was using would work with other devices
Confirmed the scanner could be detected on another computer (showed up in Device Manager) also running Windows 11 23H2
disabled Selective Suspend
Uninstalled the last security update which was applied after the last successful scan
Run sfc /scannnow with no issues found

Prior to discovering the failure, I had temporarily used that same port for a different device (a portable USB HDD).
Any thoughts?

One quick thing to try is to delete the list of USB devices from the Registry. This has no negative consequences, as the device is added back when next connected. Here are a few ways to do so.
First, unplug the scanner from USB.

Direct, but risky: open Regedit and search HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB for usbscan. Delete the key(s).

Using Device Manager:

Open a CMD prompt and anter set devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1 to show USB history.

Open Device Manager, and under View slect Show hidden devices.


Delete any grayed-out items under Universal Serial Bus Controllers and under Universal Serial Bus Devices.



Use a third-party tool such as Nirsoft's USBDeview to disconnect or uninstall any remnants.



Addendum
On this Windows 10 PC, using the epson12180.exe driver for Windows Vista, and IrfanView 4.70, 32 bit, with all plugins, I was able to get my ancient but honorable Epson 2400 to work as follows:

Press CtrlShiftA to show the Acquire/Batch scanning dialog.


Select TWAIN source and 32-bit drivers.

Use the Epson scanner dialog to capture an image to IrfanView.


In IrfanView, save the image.


This procedure might not work on Windows 11, so you might try an earlier version of Windows in a virtual machine to use that driver.

Thanks. I will give that a try tomorrow.

I have managed to get the device to appear in Device Manager as Epson Scanner but without a driver. Having a problem now finding the correct driver. The process that worked in the past is not working now.

The past process was to download/install the driver for the 4990 from the Epson website. Windows found the driver, but the installation process failed because "The hash for the file is not in the specified catalog file".

Please see addendum to answer -- I've gotten my old (and excellent!) 2400 working under Windows 10.

Working in a W10 VM is not a good option for me. However, I was able to get the scanner working with Vuescan (has its own drivers). Unfortunately, upon computer restart this morning, the scanner again is not detected on the USB ports. And the process that worked yesterday is not helpful today. So back to square 1. Might break down and get a new scanner, maybe network attached so won't have to deal with USB issues.

@RonRosenfeld, sorry it doesn't work consistently. 1. Try free IrfanView TWAIN acquisition, as well, if you can get past the USB port issue. 2. Don't discard that old scanner; it has features many of the newer ones don't.

Unfortunately, it appears that your TWAIN driver is the one installed by epson12180.exe. In Windows 11, even if I get the device to show up in device manager, installing the files from Epson breaks it. Or am I missing something?

@RonRosenfeld, yes, that driver was for Vista, and I'm not sure it's actually doing anything in Windows 10 -- it was installed years ago in Win 8, and might not be functioning. It could be the generic Windows TWAIN driver that's working.
